# Eclipse e3 to e4 migration/adaption(preferred) - recommendations

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

### What I got

I got a nearly finished e3 application, but need the dependency injection feature from e4, therefore I moved to Kepler.

Now in e4, the e3 plugins are working, if I run my application as an e3 App.
But if I change to `Application.e4xmi` the system fails. (somehow expected this)

### Problems

How can I move my e3 plugins to e4 so my perspectives and views are
working (I got plenty of em! And I cannot remove them - I need them to
be extended if an plugin gets added!)
also Menu contributions, Handlers/Commands need to work (nothing in my *fragment.e4xmi* gets added to the gui)

### What I did till now

I changed my api to e4 so I no longer use *IWorkbench* or *PlatformUI* nor *ViewPart* interfaces (still some way to go, only did this in one plugin for testing purposes)

Transformed my *plugin.xml* (e3 code) to an e4 *fragment.e4xmi* (but [found out (link to stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972865/how-to-contribute-a-new-view-in-eclipse-4-2) that contributing views/perspectives is broken in e4.)

I added the *fragment.e4xmi* as extension in my *plugin.xml* and removed everything else (e3-style)

### Resources

1. [Stackoverflow](http://www.vogella.com)
2. [Lars Vogel](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/author/jhelming/)
3. [Jonas Helming](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376486)

### Edit/Updates

1. [Bug 376486 - Eclipse 4 IDE not extendable via fragments or processors](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376486) - so how do you extend your e4 Application - if its not working via fragments or processors?
2. to raise the possibility of an solution i split up the problem and described a part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853139/eclipse-kepler-dependency-injection-in-3-x)

Comment: this [eclipse source article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/18/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/) could help a bit, [here](http://www.slideshare.net/freatt/experiences-from-porting-a-commercial-rcp-application-to-eclipse-4x) are some slides

Comment: 1st link is in my resources (already checked this one - and actually this is what i did by now) and the second one is blocked (by my companies firewall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solving this required creation of an `e3 Application` in an `e4` workspace.
then create `POJO views` and use the `Wrapper Class` to enable `DI`.

detailed solution for building it up can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853139/eclipse-kepler-dependency-injection-in-3-x)

Comment: Can you provide mode details in creating an e3 Application in an e4 workspace.  Not sure what that means.