# Eclipse Kepler Dependency Injection in 3.x

Tags: dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, e4, eclipse-kepler

I have a working plugin in Eclipse 3.7 with `Views` and a `Perspective`.
Now I try to move this to Eclipse Kepler 4.3 therefore i follow the [Tutorial from Jonas Helming](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-soft-migration-from-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/)
All my Views are based on a `TemplateView` in another Plugin. This `TemplateView` was transformed to an `e4` style `POJO` View.
My Plugin extends this `TemplateView` and adds the wrapper class (as described in the Tutorial).

Iff i run my application in `e3` style (means `TemplateView` is extending `ViewPart`) everything is fine and the `Perspective` gets added.
But when i change it to the `e4` style (means `TemplateView` is extending `POJO` and i use the Wrapper in my `plugin.xml`) eclipse does no longer dispay the `Perspective` and its `Views`.

my `e3` `View`is not really interesting, as its mostly using my custom api (which would only confuse here & it is working correctly - as it starts as `e3`)

and this is the `e4` Wrapper class:

```
import org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat.parts.DIViewPart;
import lumo.views.contact.e3.PojoDetailView;

public class E4DetailView extends DIViewPart<PojoDetailView> {
    public E4DetailView() {
        super(PojoDetailView.class);
    }
}
```

this problem is [part of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826182/eclipse-e3-to-e4-migration-adaptionpreferred-recommendations), but no dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
it is important you do use a constructer with `@Inject` `Annotation` and have `Composite parent` as parameters, then create the content. like this:

```
@Inject
public PojoDetailView(Composite parent) {
  // either put creation code here or call the 3e styled function
  createPartControl(parent);
}
```

my mistake was that i had a plain constructer and an `Annotation` `@PostConstruct` on `createPartControl(Composite parent)` (this should execute after `DI`, but obviously did not)